# Getting Request Parameter for Asynchronous Requests with Deferred Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I'm sending asynchronous HTTP requests and collecting the results. This seams the be kind of easy, after knowing what I have to look for.

Now I have the problem, that I have to associate the results of the requests with some part of the request, which I need in the `$.when`-callback, how can I do this?

```
var requests = [];
for (var i in uris) {
    requests.push($.get(endpoint, {graph: uri}));
}

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
    var result = "";

    for (i in arguments) {
        result += therequesturi: + ": (" + arguments[i][0] + ")";
    }

});
```

`therequesturi` should be a placeholder for the uri, which I've used for retrieving the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uris` array, the `requests` array and the done callback's `arguments` are all guaranteed to be congruous.

Therefore you can simply index into the original `uris` array.

Here's how I would do it :

```
var requests = uris.map(function(uri) {
    return $.get(endpoint, {graph: uri});
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);//convert arguments object to proper array.
    var result = args.map(function(res, i) {
        return uris[i] + ": (" + res[0] + ")"; // because of congruity, indexes correspond with each other.
    }).join('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue, you could need something like this:

```
var requests = [];
var results = [];

$.each(uris, function(index, uri) {
  requests.push($.get(endpoint, {graph: uri}).success(function (response) {
    results[index] = response;
  }));
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
  var result = '';

  $.each(results, function(index, r) {
    result += therequesturi + ': (' + r[0] + ')';
  }
});
```